# Do you think this tempered glass desk will hold my 50.6lbs computer?

Tags: glass, desk

I purchased this Techni Mobili L-shaped tempered glass desk up. The manual says each glass piece can hold 80lbs.  My computer weighs in at 50.6lbs and is currently resting on the corner edge of the glass right above a support beam + glass circular support thing. The glass bows only .5cm down. What I'm worried about is, since the computer is resting right on the edge, will the 80lbs rule apply and am I risking my expensive machine? Thanks

8mm thick
21 inches length
41 1/2 inches width

http://www.rtaproducts.com/_uploads/instruction-manuals/3803.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: ¿50 is less than 80? If you are worried about your computer breaking the desk anyway, put it on the floor, or buy something **unbreakable** *and darn near indestructible* like a Steelcase file cabinet and set it on that.

Comment: What happens when you set the 50 pound unit down with one foot an a piece of sandy grit?

Comment: Until you drop something hard and sharp on the surface and it shatters under the tension. Tempered glass is very strong, but very quickly turns into pebbles once its surface integrity is breached. The major reason for using it for this desk surface instead of plate glass is because of it's safer breakage failure mode, it doesn't turn into a series of long scalpels that can kill you.

Comment: Have you read this guide: http://www.overclock.net/t/715759/information-tempered-glass-office-desks ?  Many good pieces of advice centered around, oddly enough, glass desks with hulking computers on them.

Comment: Tempered glass desks are known to spontaneously shatter, even if there isn't very much weight on them. I wouldn't trust putting my whole PC on it even if it is below the weight rating.